# Card layout without inner padding on Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I create a card layout like below in Flutter?

See my code below. The card has inner padding I can't get rid of. This is needed to create the header. Also, I am not sure how to place the button with offset.

```
Card(
  elevation: 10,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    //set border radius more than 50% of height and width to make circle
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              CustomFunctions.getProductName(product.title),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          )),
      const Expanded(
          child: Center(
              child: FaIcon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.coins,
        color: CustomColors.accentColor,
      ))),
      _buildButton("${product.currencyCode}${product.price}", () => {}),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

[image]

Comment: The `Card` widget has a default `margin` of 4 px. Try to set it to `margin: EdgeInsets.zero` to get rid of the inner padding that you are mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the best way to do it, but I would create a `Stack` for this, instead of a `Card`. Here are my results:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          // SizedBox to allow for the button offset
          child: SizedBox(
            // height of the SizedBox needs to be bigger than the Container
            height: 250,
            child: Stack(
              // start alignment in topCenter so Positioned is easier
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: [
                // container for background color, rounded edges, decoration etc.
                // make sure to adjust the Padding and Container size to be the way you want
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                        child: Text('Top text'),
                      ),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 80,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                        child: Text('bottom text'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 185,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => print('button press!'),
                    child: const Text('Button'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: ss of the widget]

Answer (score 1):

This is build method inside of `Card` widget in the `card.dart`. The padding is coming from the `margin` param inside `Container`. If `margin` and `cardTheme.margin` is null, it will take the default `margin` of 4 px.

If you want to change only this instance of `Card`, set the `margin`. If you want to change all instances of `Card`, set the `margin` in `CardTheme`.

From the picture, as the widgets can be placed on top of other widgets. I recommend to use `Stack`.

```
class Card extends StatelessWidget {
    ...
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final CardTheme cardTheme = CardTheme.of(context);
        final CardTheme defaults = Theme.of(context).useMaterial3 ? _CardDefaultsM3(context) : _CardDefaultsM2(context);

        return Semantics(
            container: semanticContainer,
            child: Container(
            margin: margin ?? cardTheme.margin ?? defaults.margin!,
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.card,
              color: color ?? cardTheme.color ?? defaults.color,
              shadowColor: shadowColor ?? cardTheme.shadowColor ?? defaults.shadowColor,
              surfaceTintColor: surfaceTintColor ?? cardTheme.surfaceTintColor ?? defaults.surfaceTintColor,
              elevation: elevation ?? cardTheme.elevation ?? defaults.elevation!,
              shape: shape ?? cardTheme.shape ?? defaults.shape,
              borderOnForeground: borderOnForeground,
              clipBehavior: clipBehavior ?? cardTheme.clipBehavior ?? defaults.clipBehavior!,
              child: Semantics(
                explicitChildNodes: !semanticContainer,
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First answer actually explains quite everything. You can use `Stack` with `Positioned` to get your desired output.
2. Your unwanted padding is causing due to your use of `Column` and `Expanded` inside your card. `Column` takes infinite height, and `Expanded` takes infinite width. You can use something like `SizedBox` or other widgets with `height` and `width` properties to wrap around your card that is going constrain the size of the card.

Here is a Card widget I've used with a similar implementation I hope It will help you in your implementation:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 250,
  width: 250,
  child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
    Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 36),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 36),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                child: Text(
                  "5000 Coins",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                )),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 2),
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "80% OFF",
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headlineLarge
                      ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                ))),
            Text(
              "\$20",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            )
          ],
        )),
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      child: Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 70,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text("Image Here"),
      ),
    ),
 ]))
```

*SS Widget* screenshot:

[image: SS Widget screenshot]